# RREF of $\left[\begin{array}{c|c} A & B \end{array}\right]$ is $\left[\begin{array}{c|c} I & X\end{array}\right]$. Prove that $X=A^{-1}B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel like this is fairly straightforward, but either way I'm not too satisfied with proving this question:

Let $A$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n\times k$ matrix.  Assume that the RREF of $\left[\begin{array}{c|c} A & B \end{array}\right]$ is $\left[\begin{array}{c|c} I & X\end{array}\right]$.  Prove that $X=A^{-1}B$.

Here is what I've done:

If we multiply $B$ by $B^{-1}$ the system $[ \ A \ | \ BB^{-1} \ ]$ has RREF form $[ \ A \ | \ XB^{-1} \ ]$. However $[ \ A \ | \ BB^{-1} \ ] = [ \ A \ | \ I \ ]$ has RREF $[ \ I \ | \ A^{-1} \ ]$. Since RREF forms are unique, $A^{-1} = XB^{-1}$ which implies $X = A^{-1}B$.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to your hypothesis, $A$ is row equivalent to the identity. Therefore it is invertible. Hence, $X = A^{-1}B$.

Comment: The hypothesis also says that it is invertible .. so my entire proof is just the conclusion? Surely there are some intermediate steps I need

Comment: $X$ is the (unique) solution to $AX = B$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider multiplying the augmented matrix on the left by $A^{-1}$ (which exists through hypothesis). Through block matrix multiplication, we have
$$A^{-1}\left(A\mid B\right)=\left(A^{-1}A\mid A^{-1}B\right)=\left(I\mid A^{-1}B\right)$$
Now note that since $A^{-1}$ is invertible, it is a product of elementary matrices. Therefore we can conclude that $\left(I\mid A^{-1}B\right)$ is row equivalent to $\left(A\mid B\right)$.

In fact, it is easy to see that $\left(I\mid A^{-1}B\right)$ is actually the reduced row echelon form of $\left(A\mid B\right)$ since:

1. The leading entry of each row is $1$ and is strictly to the right of all leading entries above it.
2. Each leading entry of each row is the only non-zero element in its column.

By the uniqueness of the reduced row echelon form, we can therefore conclude that
$$\left(I\mid A^{-1}B\right)=\left(I\mid X\right)$$
and specifically, $X=A^{-1}B$.

As a note, you cannot multiply by $B^{-1}$ here. $B$ is not necessarily square so an inverse needn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The key is, to perform an *elementary row operation* on an augmented matrix is equivalent to multiplying this augmented matrix by an *[element matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix)* on the left. So, if the RREF of $(A\mid B)$ is $(I\mid X)$, this means
$$E_m \cdots E_2E_1(A\mid B)=(I\mid X)$$
for some elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_m$. Now let $M=E_m \cdots E_2E_1$. Then $(I\mid X)=M(A\mid B)=(MA\mid MB)$. Hence $MA=I$ and $MB=X$. So, $M=A^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}B=X$.